# How to enable SSL for app running inside Portainer like port 3000?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, docker

I have portainer running on Ubuntu on port 9443 SSL and I am running docker images inside portainer and one of them uses port 3000. But wondering how to make it so it can run on SSL on port 3000. My domain supports SSL already on 80 and 443 and it's running Apache2 and Nginx (outside of Portainer).

Tried googling but kind of stuck at the moment.

Comment: If that's HTTP, just create a reverse proxy. If that's a genertic service, try e.g. `stunnel`, and report any problems you've encountered with it.

Comment: Yeah that solved it. I basically created a subdomain called api.mywebsite.com and then in the nginx SSL config for that site, i did the proxy like

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }